# Comparing numbers in Calculated Column formula, inside a simple OR Condition then IF Condition is not returning Correct Value in SharePoint

Tags: list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, formula, calculated-columns

Simply trying to compare numbers in formula for calculated Column ***Total Days in Route***. The numbers to be compared are returned by subtraction like `TODAY()-[CurrentRouteDateTemp]` where the column ***CurrentRouteDateTemp*** is of type *Date*

[See column descr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRu8i.png)

Why is it still just returning the value from the main calculation i.e. `TODAY()-[CurrentRouteDateTemp]` **Why the rest of the condition not working????**

[See list view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3HRF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add value function in the formula, like this:

```
or(value(TODAY()-[CurrentRouteDateTemp])=43725,value(TODAY()-[CurrentRouteDateTemp])<0)
```

Comment: Thanks man. or works with `or(TODAY()-[CurrentRouteDateTemp]>43700,TODAY()-[CurrentRouteDateTemp]<0)` i.e. `> <` signs work but `=` sign doesn't work in case there is calculation in expression

Comment: I tried to upvote your answer and mark as accepted but I have less than 15 reputation... Don't forget to upvote my question, thanks! =)

Comment: You could accept my answer if it helps you. Only upvote  needs more than 15 reputation. Accept doesn't have any requests.